# How to create sum calculation on update after saving, before redirect, after all actions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a nested form:

```
  <%= form_for shop_product do |f| %>
   ...
    <%= f.fields_for :shop_product_print_files do |ff| %>
       <%= ff.object.print_location.title %>
          <%= ff.hidden_field :print_location_id %>
              <%= ff.select :image_file_id, options_for_select(@image_files.map { |image| [image.id, {'data-img-src'=>image.image_file_url(:thumb)}]}), {:include_blank => 'Noneblank'}, class: "image-picker" %>
       ...
```

Which on update, will reject and delete if the `:image_file_id` is blank:

**shop_product model**

```
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :shop_product_print_files, reject_if: :reject_file, :allow_destroy => true

  def reject_file(attributes)
    if attributes[:image_file_id].blank?
      if attributes[:id].present?
        attributes.merge!({:_destroy => 1}) && false
      else
        true
      end
    end
  end
```

In the update method, where the issue is:

```
@shop_product.price = (@shop_product.print_locations.to_a.sum { |sp| sp.price } + @shop_product.product.price)
```

The delete is happening AFTER the update and seems to be the last action that happens before the redirect of the successful update.

How can I create this calculation after it's updated and the records are destroyed?

I tried:

```
after_commit :calculate_price

  def calculate_price
      self.price = (self.print_locations.to_a.sum { |sp| sp.price } + self.product.price)
    end
  end
```

`after_updated`
`after_save`

Not working

To clarify as well, this calculation works on create.  the issue is because of deleting the records on update as mentioned, it kicks in before the database is changed which is why i figured `after_commit` would work.

Attempt in ShopProductPrintFile model:

```
after_commit :calculate_sp, on: [:update, :destroy]

  def calculate_sp
    shop_product = ShopProduct.find(self.shop_product.id)
      price = (shop_product.print_locations.to_a.sum { |sp| sp.price } + shop_product.product)
      shop_product.update_attributes!(price: price)
    end
  end
```

Still not working but seems like this should? Is my syntax not correct in writing?

SOLUTION:

```
  after_commit :calculate_sp

  def calculate_sp
    shop_product = ShopProduct.find(self.shop_product.id)
      price = (shop_product.print_locations.to_a.sum { |sp| sp.price } + shop_product.product.price)
    shop_product.price =  price
    shop_product.save!
  end
```

Comment: Why you cannot change order of actions, 1. delete files, 2 update price?

Comment: That/s what I was trying to figure out.  Ended up realizing I needed this ins the nested model thanks to @kuo_jimmy

Answer (score 0):

try to use `after_commit :update_product_price, on: :destroy` in your `ShopProductPrintFile` model. It will trigger when `shop_product_print_files` destroyed and you need to recalculate the price for product.

And in your example, you need to add `save!` to your `after_commit` or it won't save to database. But you should be careful that it will trigger another update to product model and trigger `after_commit` again. so you have to add a condition to detect if `after_commit` should be triggered.

Comment: Okay this makes more sense.  I tried a few different ways but still not working? I updated my OP at the bottom with 1 of the attemps

Answer (score 0):

This works with putting in my ShopProductPrintFile model.

On update, create, and destroy.

```
  after_commit :calculate_sp

  def calculate_sp
    shop_product = ShopProduct.find(self.shop_product.id)
      price = (shop_product.print_locations.to_a.sum { |sp| sp.price } + shop_product.product.price)
    shop_product.price =  price
    shop_product.save!
  end
```

I will not be accepting this response as I am sure there is a better way or syntax for doing this.  If you have this, please respond with it and why it is a more efficient or better approach and I will accept yours